How do I check if the width of the image is > 80% and if it is, set width to 80% in JavaScript?
My HTML is this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Aerocello</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<body>
    <div class="gallery" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index;">
        <img src="logo2.png" alt="logo" class="centre">
        <script>
            // if (what goes here?) {
                // and here
            // }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="idk">
        <p class="roboto">hi</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

and my CSS is this:
body {
    background-color: #AEAEAE;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    height: 100vh;
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.centre {
    width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
   overflow: auto;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.roboto {
    font-family: roboto;
}

So, My image's height is 80% and the width is set proportional to that but I want to check if width is over 80% and if it is set it to 80% and set the height to be proportional to the new width. How do I do that in JavaScript?
I didn't try anything really, I didn't know where to start?

Have you explored using the CSS max-width property to style the element?

Is there any reason you need to do this in JS rather than following @Pointy suggestion and  just setting max-width and max-height to 80% and letting CSS alter things proportionally? CSS would have the advantage over JS - JS would need to be explicitly called every time the parent changed size.

This can be solved with CSS; no Javascript required. Set both the width and the height to 80%, then use object-fit: contain.


html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">




<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        const images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");

        images.forEach(image => {
            image.onload = () => {
                const parentWidth = image.parentElement.clientWidth;
                const imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
                const imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;

                if (imageWidth > 0.8 * parentWidth) {
                    image.style.width = "80%";
                    image.style.height = "auto";
                } else {
                    image.style.height = "80%";
                    image.style.width = "auto";
                }
            };
        });
    };
</script>



While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. See How do I write a good answer?.

This doesn't guarantee that the resultant height is <=80%.
